# How to call rewards block phtml content into minicart section magento 2?

Tags: magento2, html, mini-cart, magento-enterprise-2, magento-reward

**`Magento 2 Enterprise,`**

With `Magento Reward module`, 
Inside layout file **`checkout_cart_index.xml`** file with reward block is defined as below.

```
<block class="Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout" name="reward.tooltip.checkout" template="tooltip.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="reward_type" xsi:type="string">Magento\Reward\Model\Action\OrderExtra</argument>
    </arguments>
    <action method="setWrapperClass">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">reward-checkout</argument>
    </action>
    <action method="setRewardMessage">
        <argument translate="true" name="message" xsi:type="string">Check out now and earn %1 for this order.</argument>
    </action>
    <action method="setIsGuestNote">
        <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

I want to this reward blocks html content into Checkout module **`Customerdata/Cart.php`** file,

How can i call above block content into

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php** file with below function,

```
public function getSectionData()
{
    $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();      
    return [
        'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),                        
        'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
            ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue())
            : 0,
        'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
        'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
        'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
        'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        'rewards' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout','reward.tooltip.checkout')    
                  ->toHtml(),
    ];
}
```

I have try to call this block using,

> 'rewards' =>
>   $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout','reward.tooltip.checkout')->toHtml(),

**But rewards always return null**

In same calling in `minicart.phtml` file,

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout','reward.tooltip.checkout')->toHtml()
```

Result,

> Check out now and earn 100 Reward points for this order. Learn more
>   This applies only to registered users and may vary when a user is
>   logged in.

In above function with rewards argument, I want result of **reward.toottip.checkout** phtml content using above way.

How to resolve this issue in magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Solved issue using pass parent class construct dependency.

**Just Pass ParentObject construct dependency inside `createBlock()`  method and its working fine for getting html content of template file.**

```
public function getSectionData()
    {
        $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();

        //for rewards point
        $rewards = $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout','reward.tooltip.checkout',
            [
                'data' => ['reward_type' => 'Magento\Reward\Model\Action\OrderExtra',
                           'rewardHelper' => 'Magento\Reward\Helper\Data',
                           'customerSession' => 'Magento\Customer\Model\Session',
                           'rewardInstance' => 'Magento\Reward\Model\Reward',
                           'storeManager' => 'Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager'
                          ]
            ]);
        $rewards->setWrapperClass('reward-checkout')->setRewardMessage("Check out now and earn %1 for this order.")->setIsGuestNote(1);
        $rewards->setTemplate('Magento_Reward::tooltip.phtml'); 

        return [
            'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),                        
            'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
                ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue())
                : 0,
            'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
            'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
            'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
            'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
            'rewards' => $rewards->toHtml(),
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change function as below in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php`

```
public function getSectionData()
{
    $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();      
    $rewards = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout','reward.tooltip.checkout'
        );
        $rewards->setTemplate('Magento_Reward::tooltip.phtml');         

    return [
        'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),                        
        'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
            ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue())
            : 0,
        'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
        'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
        'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
        'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        'rewards' => $rewards->toHtml(),
    ];
}
```

Please have a try, I have not tested

Comment: Return null using above case.

Comment: Please confirm Magento_Reward module name and change it if different

Comment: yes i have checked this is correct module name but always return null. I have worked on enterprise edition.

Comment: Just try any default magento block and get content is not working.

Comment: Please change `$this->getLayout()->` to `$this->layout->`

Comment: I have already used that.

Comment: Please have a try, `$rewards = $this->layout->createBlock(
            'Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout','reward.tooltip.checkout',
   ['reward_type' => 'Magento\Reward\Model\Action\OrderExtra']
        );`

Comment: Issue are solved by set parent construct class inside createblock method.